# Jmeter: Binary File Upload Fails with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, performance-testing, internal-server-error

I have tried to upload a binary file, which works fine using POSTMAN as below:

**Request Headers:**

[image]

**Request Parameter:**

[image]

**Request Body:**

[image]

Here it works just fine.

I have tried the same Request Header and Body in **Jmeter**, but getting **500 internal server Error**.
Please take a look into the below Jmeter configurations:

**HTTP Request Parameter:**

[image]

**HTTP Request File Upload:**

[image]

I am a new bee to JMeter. Can someone help me and let me know what is wrong in the configuration I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some mismatch in terms of [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), if you can successfully execute the request using Postman you should be able to record the same using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/proxy/)

   [image]
3. [Copy the file you will be uploading to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/)
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will save the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler along with the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. 

I have tried recording the Jmeter Upload functionality using Blazemeter, but after exporting it as .jmx and executing the same test in Jmeter, the script is failing with same 500 Internal Server Error, even without disturbing any of the recorded inputs.

Comment: I have tried recording the POSTMAN script from JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and I have found the missing HTTP Header.
The solution worked for me. 
Thank you @Dmitri